# Update-Packages hash sum mismatch due to GPG error

Tags: linux-mint, packages, md5sum

```
syndaemon: no process found
/etc/mdm/Xsession: Beginning session setup...
localuser:imnobody being added to access control list
Script for none started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service
Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service
Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service
Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service
Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service
Script for none started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
```

My system was working fine till morning and has been for months, but suddenly when I tried to boot this evening I got the above error when it couldn't log in. Before inserting a live cd to check full errors, I simply rebooted it and this time it prompted to fix the problem on it's own or manually do it or ignore it. I opted for the system to fix and it booted and log in was successful. Then on opening I found the windows update manager with the red mark stating these errors below.

```
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A7D1D38BEB6D886
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: Failed to fetch http://extra.linuxmint.com/dists/rosa/m ... 4/Packages Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.linuxmint.com/dists/ros ... 4/Packages Hash Sum mismatch
```

I did try fixing it following this link.[trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error) but it didn't work. I still have the same error. Does this mean I won't get any updates from those sources anymore?. What should I do?

PS: To my knowledge I don't think these two are related but posted it just in case because pc was without any such errors before it.

Answer (score 0):

I also posted my question on linux mint subreddit and that solved it for me and link to the thread is here [updatepackages_hash_sum_mismatch](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/6vmiga/updatepackages_hash_sum_mismatch/)